# AttributeError: module 'urwid' has no attribute 'Text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, archlinux, pypi, urwid

I want to program in urwid. But after pip install of package "urwid".If i want to check the package with simple program like this:

```
import urwid
txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')
loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
loop.run()
```

and save it as some_name.py . Error is thrown, while running in terminal like:

```
$ python <some_name>.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urwid.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urwid
  File "/home/<user's directory>/<some_name>.py", line 2, in <module>
    txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
AttributeError: module 'urwid' has no attribute 'Text'
```

if you want to see list of python package installed in my system is:

```
$ pip list
appdirs (1.4.0)
Brlapi (0.6.5)
chardet (2.3.0)
cupshelpers (1.0)
Cython (0.25.1)
isc (2.0)
louis (3.0.0)
packaging (16.8)
pip (8.1.2)
psutil (5.0.0)
pycups (1.9.73)
pycurl (7.43.0)
pygobject (3.22.0)
pyparsing (2.1.10)
pyxdg (0.25)
requests (2.11.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
simplejson (3.10.0)
six (1.10.0)
team (1.0)
termcolor (1.1.0)
urllib3 (1.19.1)
urwid (1.3.1)
youtube-dl (2016.11.14.1)
```

version of pip i have installed is

```
$pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

please help me out!!Thanks in advance

Comment: What name have you saved it as? It executes without issues for me; make sure you're not saving as `urwid.py` thereby masking the library you're trying to use.

Comment: I previously saved it as urwid.py now after your suggestion i try with other name but not worked for me. im using archlinux OS.

Comment: have you deleted the previously named `urwid.py`?

Comment: yeah...i deleted  it and now its running super fast. Thanks... for correcting my mistake  #Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard

Answer (score 3):

Issues like this only happen in two cases:

- There is a file in your current directory same name as one of the imported libraries.
- You have named the file same as one of your imported libraries.

The library, in this case, is `urwid`.